# display the sorted order of live data from database using html/angular2

Tags: html, mysql, angular

I am trying to display the sorted order of the live data coming from database and displaying on the webpage. When I click on the column name, it gets sorted in ascending or descending order. I want to display the sorted order for the user with an HTML field Eg:  "Sorted by: Name Ascending" or Sorted by: date Descending".
Can you please help me how to do this using angular2 and html ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0):

You can read this blog about table sorting and filter. [Table Sorting and Filtering](https://scotch.io/tutorials/sort-and-filter-a-table-using-angular)